# Making a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm tryin to create a list that is made it with another list:
[[1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8]] The thing here is that when I append with
np.append() a list to another this is nesting instead of maintaining a list separate from each other, like this: [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]] Here is my code:

```
class poblacion:

    def generar(self):
        poblacion_p = np.random.randint(0,4,(10,10))
        print (poblacion_p)
        self.individuos(poblacion_p)

    def individuos(self, poblacion_p):
        individuo1=poblacion_p[0]
        individuo2=poblacion_p[1]
        individuo3=poblacion_p[2]
        individuo4=poblacion_p[3]
        individuo5=poblacion_p[4]
        individuo6=poblacion_p[5]
        individuo7=poblacion_p[6]
        individuo8=poblacion_p[7]
        individuo9=poblacion_p[8]
        individuo10=poblacion_p[9]
        aptitudes = [1,3,5,7,9,11,12,14,19,20]
        nueva_g=[]
        aptitud = random.choices(aptitudes, weights=(5,15,25,35,45,63,65,67,75,80), k = 10)
        for c in aptitud:
            if (c == 20):
                nueva_g = np.append(nueva_g, individuo1)
            elif (c == 19):
                nueva_g = np.append(nueva_g, individuo8)
            elif (c == 14):
                nueva_g = np.append(nueva_g, individuo2)
            elif (c == 12):
                nueva_g = np.append(nueva_g, individuo6)
            elif (c == 11):
                nueva_g = np.append(nueva_g, individuo3)
            elif (c == 9):
                nueva_g = np.append(nueva_g, individuo9)
            elif (c == 7):
                nueva_g = np.append(nueva_g, individuo4)
            elif (c == 5):
                nueva_g = np.append(nueva_g, individuo7)
            elif (c == 3):
                nueva_g = np.append(nueva_g, individuo5)
            elif (c == 1):
                nueva_g = np.append(nueva_g, individuo10)
        print(aptitud)
        print(nueva_g)
```

When I run the code the list of poblacion_p is in the form that I
want:

```
[[3 2 1 1 0 0 1 3 0 0], 
[2 2 2 0 0 2 0 1 1 3], 
[3 3 0 0 1 3 3 1 1 3], 
[3 2 3 3 3 0 1 1 3 0], 
[3 1 2 0 3 2 2 0 0 1], 
[2 2 3 3 3 2 1 1 0 0],  
[2 3 2 0 3 1 1 3 2 0], 
[1 3 3 3 0 2 0 1 2 2], 
[3 1 1 2 3 1 3 3 3 2], 
[3 0 3 1 3 3 1 1 0 0]]
```

But when I try to append the rows that randomly selects the program in
a new list happens this:

```
[3. 2. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 3. 0. 0. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 2. 1. 1. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 2. 0. 1. 1. 3. 3. 3. 0. 0. 1. 3. 3. 1. 1. 3. 2. 3. 2. 0. 3. 1. 1. 3. 2. 0. 3. 1. 1. 2. 3. 1. 3. 3. 3. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 2. 1. 1. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 2. 0. 1. 1. 3. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 2. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 3. 3. 3. 0. 2. 0. 1. 2. 2.]
```

Does anyone know how to keep the lists separate from each other?

Comment: If you want a list of lists, why are you using `np.append`?  Why not list append method?

Comment: You aren't creating lists at all. `numpy.append` creates a `numpy.ndarray`. Why aren't you just using `neuava_g.append`???

Comment: `np.append` flattens its inputs and joins them as one 'line'.  That's why the result is 1 dimensional.  On the surface it looks like a list append, but gives problems if you don't read the docs with enough care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use `append()` method of list object like this:

```
for c in aptitud:
        if (c == 20):
            nueva_g.append(individuo1)
        elif (c == 19):
            nueva_g.append(individuo8)
        elif (c == 14):
            nueva_g.append(individuo2)
```

EDIT

As per the suggestion, if you wanted to rework the code you could use a dictionary as a map for this kind of problem.
Something like this would work well.

```
MAP = {20: 0,
       19: 7,
       14: 1}

for c in aptid:
    nueva_g.append(poblacion_p[MAP[c]])
```

This only caters for the few examples I've given above, and I'd also probably restructure so the data is in a more logical order, but maybe there is a reason for that as it's being run in a for loop. This is untested but the general idea is sound.

You could also wrap the dictionary method in a switch function. Or as of Python 3.10 you could use the inbuilt switch statement.

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html

Comment: That is the minimal change. However, the code could do with redesigning so that there are not 10 separate variables `individuo1`, `individuo2`, ... and lots of `elif`s  Probably the relevant row from `poblacion_p` should be extracted when needed.

Comment: @alani yep agreed

Comment: Oh I see, I will redesign the code but this solved my problem, thanks!